# What's up with my Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer

Please, can you look at the pics. This wrong thing I take in all open file dialogs. What is it? Can you help me fix it? Thanx.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are there some interface tweakers installed? What have you done before this stuff happened?

Comment: @at8eqeq3, No, nothing is installed. But some time earlier I've modified my registry, because I wanted to make Explorer (when I can see to separated tabs: folders left and content right) my default folder viewer, when I open My Computer, but I it doesn't seem to me that I've made something wrong.

Comment: try to look this settings: run `gpedit.msc` and navigate to User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Explorer > Common Open File Dialog > Items displayed in Places Bar (Конфигурация пользователя > Административные шаблоны > Компоненты Windows > Проводник > Общее диалоговое окно открытия файлов > Элементы, отображаемые в панели мест)

Comment: Yahooooo, I fixed it! Thanx you a lot lot lot!

Comment: @at8eqeq3 post that as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To configure Places bar, run `gpedit.msc` and navigate to User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Explorer > Common Open File Dialog > Items displayed in Places Bar

Comment: FWIW, Windows Home or below does not have gpedit.